# Cygwin/Linux - Find files which contain strings from a file

Tags: linux, unix, grep, cygwin

I am trying to find files which contain strings located in a text file within their file names and then copy these files to a new directory.

```
Example 1.txt contains strings line by line:
1234
1666

Directory contains files:
JOHN-1234-TEXT.CSV
DAVE-1666-TEXT.CSV
LAURA-1826-TEXT.CSV

If code is successful it will copy the files to a new specified directory:
JOHN-1234-TEXT.CSV
DAVE-1666-TEXT.CSV
```

If anyone can i help i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Make sure your pattern file has unix line ending, i.e. `\n` not `\r\n`. Use `d2u` or `dos2unix` to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**find** + **grep** + **tr** + **xargs** *pipeline* approach:

```
find olddir -type f -print | grep -f "1.txt" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} newdir
```

---

`olddir` directory contains the initial files

`grep -f "1.txt"` - obtains patterns from file, one per line

Comment: @kayboxa, you should specify your actual directory names instead of `olddir` and `newdir` (it should work fine)

Answer (score 0):

quick solution :

```
while read line;do
    find -iname "*$line*" -exec cp {} newdir/ \;
done < string_file
```